# vscode extension limit quickpick to only show N items for shorter height

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extension to search/grep content of the current document, but the quickpick by default shows 20 items that **blocks** the view of the content being searched. Is there a way to limit the quick pick to fewer items?

extension link [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wenhoujx.swiper)

[image: quickpick blocks content]
thanks

Comment: I don't think the number of displayed items can be changed in this way.  This request was similar but failed to gain traction: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111146

Comment: @Mark sad times. thanks for commenting